# How can I turn this txt file to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I receive txt file in below structure every week:

[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU5tH.jpg)

And I would like to turn it into Dataframe which looks like below:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRu8X.jpg)

The challenging part is:

1. The date of some LICENSE is different from others such as CQ_XHO_N1 which doesn't have data on 4 Feb 2016.
2. When I receive more txt file next week I need to append the data on the existing dataframe and update the total percentage.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stack overflow. Providing an example dataset will help others help you. Regardless, you're going to want to take a look at [```pd.read_csv```](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. However the file format is txt rather than csv. I know how to read the txt file but don't know how to turn that to dataframe in certain format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MrSmily2019 said you will want to use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html.

It does more than just CSV, it can do text. Additionally you can turn text files into csv. You file seems to be "TAB" delimited (how it know to separate) instead of comma. You can adjust the settings so it knows to do it on the appropriate character.

And example of how you would have to modify it is:

```
pandas.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')
```